# How can I create a APNS Platform application on Simple Notification Service (SNS) using AWS PHP SDK?

Tags: php, amazon-web-services, apple-push-notifications, aws-sdk

I'm having some problems to create a Platform Application on SNS using php AWS SDK to Apple APNS.

I created an GCM application and it's working fine, but I have no idea of how to create a PlataformApplication  to APNS.

Any one can show me an example?

I have the necessary certificates but I don't know how to use it.

The code that I'm using to create the GCM Plataform Application is:

```
$result = $this->_sns->createPlatformApplication(array(
  'Name'       => Yii::app()->params['SNS_APPLICATION_NAME'],
  'Platform'   => 'GCM',
  'Attributes' => array('PlatformCredential' => Yii::app()->params['GCM_API_KEY']),
));
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I finally found the answer of this question. To create a APNS platform application ARN is very simple.

After you generate the .pem certificate, you just need to separate the content of this file in two different files (private_key and certificate), and call the aws sis client like this:

```
  $result = $this->_sns->createPlatformApplication(array(
    'Name'       => Yii::app()->params['SNS_APPLICATION_NAME'],
    'Platform'   => 'APNS_SANDBOX',
    'Attributes' => array(
      'PlatformCredential' => file_get_contents(dirname(__FILE__) . '/../runtime/key.txt'),
      'PlatformPrincipal'  => file_get_contents(dirname(__FILE__) . '/../runtime/certificate.txt'),
    ),
  ));
```

It will generate a APNS_SANDBOX or APNS platform applications ARN depending of your certificate.

I hope this help.

Thanks.